# Find a prefix string, aggregate, mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have a simple data like this

```
{
 _id:1,
 code: "LAZ0101"
},
{
 _id:2,
 code: "LAZ1102"
},
{
 _id:3,
 code: "LAZA0101"
},
{
 _id:4,
 code: "LAZAB102"
}
```

how can i group data with aggregate like this

```
{
 _id: "LAZ",
 count: 2
},
{
 _id: "LAZA",
 count: 2
}
```

Is this possible with the aggregation framework?

Comment: How are the groups determined? Is it always `"LAZ#"` is one group and `"LAZA"` is the other?

Comment: I just wanna group with length is 4 and then reduce 1 with the rest of the data

Comment: I still don't think that is clear though. If you were grouping by the first 4 characters, then you would have 3 entries for the sample data (`LAZ0`, `LAZ1`, and `LAZA`) right?

Answer (score 0):

use `$substr` and subtract the first 4 character then `$group` and after using `$cond` subtract the string that are not grouped

test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nBF-ICQCwdh)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      code: {
        $substr: [
          "$code",
          0,
          4
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$code",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: 1,
      _id: {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $gt: [
              "$count",
              1
            ]
          },
          "then": "$_id",
          "else": {
            $substr: [
              "$_id",
              0,
              3
            ]
          }
        },
        
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "count": {
        "$sum": "$count"
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very helpful but i don't wanna just subtract 4 letter of string. i want use `$substr ["$code",0,4]` and use continue `$substr ["$code", 0, 3]` for what remains of the ungrouped data

Comment: does https://mongoplayground.net/p/nBF-ICQCwdh answer your question?

Comment: This answer can solve my problem. Thank you very much! +1